# c++ android ndk work with array

Tags: android, c++, arrays, android-ndk

I have a big problem, i'm not used with c++. I'm passing an array from java to c++ through jni and i want to create inside c++ a new array of the same length . Here is the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>


extern "C"
{

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_profesionphotostudio_pps_Imageprocessing_process(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jintArray pixelArray, jintArray ddimensions, jint function)
{

    int *pixels = env->GetIntArrayElements( pixelArray, 0);
    jsize length = env->GetArrayLength(pixelArray);
    int *d= env->GetIntArrayElements(ddimensions, 0);


    int i, j, pixel, red, green, blue, h,w;

    w=d[0]; h =d[1];


    int *temppixel= new int[length];
    for(i=0; i<=w*h; i++)
    {
        temppixel[i]=-1;
    }
    delete [] temppixel;
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements( pixelArray, pixels, 0);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(ddimensions, d, 0);
 }
```

But i receive this error:

```
    Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00097756 (code=1), thread 9082 (photostudio.pps)
```

when i set manually

```
 length = 100000;
```

my code works just fine. I've also tried to set

```
length = w*h;
```

but i receive the same fatal signal error

in ddimensions array i keep height and width of a bitmap and pixelArray contains int values of that bitmap

Comment: If you log the values of `length`, `d[0]`, `d[1]`, what does it show?

Comment: @Madalin Have you tried to change `for(i=0; i<=w*h; i++)` to `for(i=0; i< length; i++)`

Comment: Yes, but it shows me the same error

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for(i=0; i<=w*h; i++)
```

By

```
for(i=0; i<w*h; i++)
```

Or you'll access the array out of its bound (array indexes go from `0` to `n-1`).

The code works, whatever value of `w` and `h` (at least positive ones):

```
int h = 10;
int w = 15;
int *temppixel = new int[w*h];
for(i=0; i<w*h; i++)
{
    temppixel[i] = -1;
}
delete [] temppixel;
```

This is definitely valid in C++. If it still crashs, the problem must come from somewhere else (then you need to isolate the problem).

Comment: Nope, it still crashes

Comment: Have you tried with small w and h? Maybe if they are too big Android does not permit you to allocate a huge amount of memory.

Comment: I've tested that before posting this question, memory its not a problem. I've set w = 1000; h=6000; and it runs without problems

Comment: This C++ is definitely correct. Put only the 11 lines of code I posted in your Java_com_profesionphotostudio_pps_Imageprocessing_process function and confirm it works. Then, add your code calling env methods and later replace w and h by what you actually want. If you do this in an iterative way, running your program again after every change, you'll end up figuring what instruction causes the crash.

Comment: Thanks, i've figured out what the mistake was, thanks a lot

Comment: Post an answer then. It may help someone else

Comment: In java part  i've already set width = bmp.getwidth() - 1; and height = bmp.getheight()-1;  dumb me

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not getting the length of the array in the function right, it should be like this:

jsize length = env->GetArrayLength(env, pixelArray);

Comment: My code is written in c++ and this is the correct syntax

Comment: In c it would be jsize length =(* env)->GetArrayLength(env, pixelArray);